# retrieve random id_post sql

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have this table:

```
+---------+------+
| id_post | post |
+---------+------+
| 24      | A    |
| 26      | B    |
| 39      | C    |
| 57      | D    |
+---------+------+
```

I want to retrieve the a random `id_post`

```
SELECT id_post
FROM  posts
WHERE rand()
```

I would like to retrieve a single value `24`, `26`, `39` or `57`.

How can I make that work?

Comment: How large is your table?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, postgres, sql-server...?

Comment: its for a large table in mysql/pdo thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only four rows, it doesn't much matter how you do it.  However, if you have a large table, you would like to limit the amount of data being sorted.

One method is:

```
select p.id_post
from posts p cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from posts) pp
where rand() < 100.0 / pp.cnt
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

Although this requires scanning the table, it does not require sorting the entire table.

Comment: thank you. this is for a large table. What would be the difference between your answer and the one posted below? yours looks like a bit mor complex. I would lime to know which option would be suitable for a large table, thank you. Or if both are suitable. thank you.

Comment: @max . . . This scans the table once and then there is a cost of sorting 100 rows, which is quite small.  The cost of sorting the entire table is much larger.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `ORDER BY RAND()` and `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT id_post
FROM  posts
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

You did not tell which database you are using. The actual syntax for `RAND()` and `LIMIT 1` does vary accross databases. The above would work in MySQL. There are equivalent syntaxes in other databases, for example:

Postgres:

```
SELECT id_post
FROM  posts
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP (1) id_post
FROM  posts
ORDER BY newid()
```